# Having problems with TabControls

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, selectedindex

I am trying to change a tabpage name on a parent form to what a user types in a textbox on a child form when a strip menu button is clicked. I have everything working in that I can pull the correct information between both forms but every time it goes to get the currently selected tabpage it always returns "0".

**Function to set new tabpage name on Forum1 (The message boxes are from trying to debug)**

```
public void setNewTabName(string TextBoxText)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Called");
        MessageBox.Show(TextBoxText);
        int CurrentSelectedTab = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
        MessageBox.Show(CurrentSelectedTab.ToString());
        tabControl1.TabPages[CurrentSelectedTab].Text = TextBoxText;
    }
```

**Function (Form2) for getting the textbox info and passing it to Form1**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         BT frm1 = new BT();
         frm1.setNewTabName(getTextBoxInfo());
     }

    public string getTextBoxInfo()
     {
         return textBox1.Text;
     }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think I posted all the relevant code but if you need anything else I can post the whole thing. The only thing that is really left out is that it creates a new tabpage on a button click.

Edit: The same method works fine when it is taken out of the child GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you create a new form (class BT) each time the button is clicked. I suggest you to move the form creation from button click event to parent form load function.

Comment: That doesn't seem to affect anything, although I did move it to another location. When using the MessageBox.Show the last one I get displays the "CurrentSelectedTab" as 0 even though the currently selected tab is not 0. I think it may have something to do with the window not being active but don't have much experience in c# to know how to fix it.